# Android Studio Blackberry plug-in - can't repackage APK to BAR

Tags: android, android-studio, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-android

I'm trying to repackage my fully compatible Android app to Blackberry's BAR format.

I've tested the application extensively in the simulator using Blackberry's ADB Proxy, so I know Android Studio sees the RIM "device," but the option is grayed out.  My signing token keystore, the csk file, is placed in the correct directory, %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Research In Motion.

Is repackaging possible without using a physical device?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Solved.  You first have to generate a signed APK and place it in the app folder inside your project directory:

[Project Directory]\app\app-release.apk